# Getting information from minidumps that have WerReportFault() on the stack

Tags: debugging, vb6, windbg, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I have crash dumps that have `WerpReportFault()` in their stack and they really don't look the way I expect them to.

#### My expectation

If have seen `WerpReportFault()`along with 0x80000003 breakpoints and I was able to use WinDbg to re-dump with different exception pointers, taken from the second argument passed to `WerpReportFault()`.

I'm very sure that has worked before, since I even recommended that in [my answer over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022461/480982). There are also other sites suggesting this technique, e.g. [James Ross](https://james-ross.co.uk/weblog/2013/02/25/01)

#### My current observations

The dumps I'm analyzing have an "ordinary exception" inside, e.g. an access violation:

```
0:000> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 53ec8b55
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 53ec8b55
Attempt to read from address 53ec8b55
```

But they still have `WerpReportFault()` as the stack:

```
0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0018f25c 74c4171a ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15
0018f2f8 75181a08 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x100
0018f340 75184200 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xe0
0018f35c 751a80ec kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
0018f3c8 751a7fab kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+0x186
0018f3dc 751a78a0 kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x70
0018f3ec 751a781f kernel32!BasepReportFault+0x20
0018f478 7295fa2e kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1af
```

Argument 2 does not seem to be a good exception pointer to be used in the `.dump` command.

```
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
[...]
0018f3dc 751a78a0 0018f4a0 00000001 0018f478 kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x70
[...]
```

#### Question

What causes the problems I have and how do I get around it? I know it must be possible, because `!analyze -v` can tell me the real call stack.

Is it due to Visual Basic 6 and the unhandled exception filter?

```
0018f478 7295fa2e 00000000 72a2bd04 0018f4a8 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1af
0018ff80 00440fe2 00443860 7518338a 7efde000 msvbvm60!Zombie_Release+0x10fd5
```

I really want to have a nice call stack, since all my manual debugging and all my scripts are broken which rely on `k` and `!clrstack` and similar. They can't deal with `WerpReportFault()` on the stack.

All the dumps are 32 bit, as you can imagine from the VB6 dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a problem is caused by a wrong context. It seems to be set to the normal context record. To set it to the exception context, use `.ecxr`. To switch back to the normal context (which you see), use `.cxr`